# SwiftyJSON not working / Swift 1.2 SwiftyJSON file

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

When I added my SwiftyJSON file to my project, it had like 45 errors where about 44 of them were changing `as` to `as!`. Now I'm stuck at the last one on line 238 before I'm good to go. The error says:

Cannot assign a value of type 'AnyObject' to a value of type 'AnyObject!'

and the code looks like this:

```
    set {
            if self.type == .Array {
                var array_: AnyObject = self.object as![AnyObject]
                if array_.count > index {
                    array_[index] = newValue.object
                    self.object = array_
                }
            }
        }
```

The error is in the line with `array_[index] = newValue.object`.

Please help me figure this one out, thanks in advance.

Comment: You're using a version of Xcode that's incompatible with the code base (i.e. Xcode 6.3 beta / Swift 1.2 when SwiftyJSON master branch targets Swift 1.2). Use [this branch](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/tree/xcode6.3) instead.

Comment: @mattt You meant "SwiftyJSON master branch targets Swift 1.1," not 1.2, right?

Comment: @mattt Thank you, please submit as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a branch named 'xcode6.3' which seems to be compatible. If using Cocoapods, you can change the Podfile to point at the branch as follows:

`pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git', :branch => 'xcode6.3'`

Comment: as of May-2015 this branch doesnt exist any more